# Adding to the Where clause of an Update in LinQ-to-Entities

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Let's say I have a table called Product, with three columns: Id, CustomerId, Name. Id is the primary key.  The schema is outside of the control of my group, and we now have a requirement to always provide CustomerId as a parameter for all queries (selects, updates, deletes).  It's a long story I'd rather not get into ... it involves triggers :-P

So my question is, when I have an attached entity in LinqToEntities, and I want to save some updates (say I'm updating the name in this case).  How can I get it to generate the SQL:

```
update Product set Name = @Name where Id=@Id and CustomerId=@CustomerId
```

Where the customerId parameter is included in the where clause in addition to the primary key.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does the CustomerId help uniquely identify the row past @Id? I didn't really follow the "triggers" bit, since the predicate used for the update is not known by the trigger. Or you do want to re-update the CustomerId each time (detectable from `UPDATE(...)` in the trigger)

The easiest option is to do it as object updates:

```
var qry = from product in model.Products
          where Id == @Id && CustomerId == @CustomerId
          select product;

foreach(Product p in qry) {
    p.Name = @Name;
}

model.SaveChanges(); // or whatever the method is in EF
```

If you know you are expecting one record, you could use:

```
Product prod = (from product in model.Products
          where Id == @Id && CustomerId == @CustomerId
          select product).Single();

prod.Name = @Name;
mode.SaveChanges(); // ditto
```

You **might** also be able to write it as Entity-SQL, but I'm not sure I'd bother, personally... (update: I've just checked, and I don't think Entity-SQL includes DML, so no, you can't - you'd have to use either the above, or a regular SQL command/SPROC)

Comment: The CustomerId is not part of the primary key, but because of some triggers in place by the DBAs, it *must* be in the update statement's Where clause.  So the above wouldn't work because save changes would ultimately make an update statement with only Id=@Id in the where clause :-(

Comment: But neither would your code (if it worked); to be useful in triggers, you need it in the *UPDATE SET*, not the *WHERE*.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to [use a stored proc to do the update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716731.aspx). This gives you complete control over the SQL.

Another way is to add the CustomerId to the entity key.

Comment: we would like to avoid sprocs at almost all costs ... trying to avoid re-writing a lot of code which already exists as LINQ updates